# Alt + F7 keyboard shortcut does not work on a netbook

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts, x86

I am running Android 2.2 on a netbook (Android x86).

The keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> doesn't lead me back to graphics screen (GUI) from the console.

Does anyone know any alternative to this shortcut?

Answer (score 6):

This shortcut key problem is conflicted with NVIDIA GeForce Experience app's shortcut key in Windows.

Please refer this out: 
http://duongame.tistory.com/414

Comment: Answers that are really just external links are not good for SO. Can you paraphrase the germane parts here in English?

Comment: Thanks, I disabled the setting into GeForce Experience and it helped to me.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such shortcut defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html). Also on the same page you can see that to use console you need Telnet.